# Someone is both my 1st and 2nd cousin, is there a name for that, or do you pick the closest level of relationship (1st cousin)?

Tags: kinship-terminology

Dora is my grandaunt's (maternal grandmother's sister's) daughter, which makes her my 1st Cousin 1x removed. Therefore Dora's children would be my 2nd cousins.

However, my paternal Uncle William married Dora. So Dora is now my aunt and her children are my 1st cousins.

Dora and William had a daughter named Betty. Is Betty both my 1st and 2nd cousin?

Does this mean Dora is my Aunt in law as well as my 1st cousin 1x removed?

For family tree making purposes I have been choosing the person's closest relationship to me, so Dora is marked as my aunt, and Betty as my 1st cousin. Just wondering how this is typically handled.

Here is an attempt at making a visual
[image]

Comment: You and Betty are not first cousins because you do not share a grandparent.

Comment: @PolyGeo Uncle William's parents are my grandparents as well as Betty's grandparents. I updated my visual to include those common grandparents.

Comment: I don't think your diagram reflects that.  The first change that I would make to your diagram is to prepend each use of Grandfather and Grandmother with Paternal or Maternal.